# How do I get UC (Credits) in Infinity Field?

Tags: ios, infinity-field

So in campaign I'm getting some credits to buy upgrades and stuff, but I don't know what affects how much I get per level.

Do I get a set amount for getting so many stars? So many points? If it varies, what gives me the most credits?

Comment: Buying this game right now; will post when I get the answer.